# Temperature rises in Ubuntu 64 bit with Embedded PC intel corei3 2100T/Chipset Q67(cpu throttling)

Tags: temperature

Why does Industrial Fanless Embedded CPU Intel® Core™ i3-2100T with chipset intel Q67 gets hang in ubuntu 64 Bit.HDD suddenly stopping in video signal application and temperature rising but in windows works fine.